# Messy data in excel: importing using pandas; multiple occurrence of variables in columns

Tags: python, pandas

I do have an excel file with up to 100 measurements produced by a stupid export function. Each measurement consists of 200 rows :

```
Name1                                      Name2
' some other stuff related to the measurements'    
v    Qv    vm    qlnv    'empty column'    v    Qv    vm    qlnv
1    2     3    4                          5    6     7     8
```

I do import it:

```
df = pd.read_excel('data.xls',skiprows = 2, indexcol=None)
```

Afterwards

```
df_1500.dropna(axis=1, inplace = True)
df_1500.columns
```

gives me:

`Index([ u'v', u'Qv', u'vm', u'qlnv', u'v.1', u'Qv.1', u'vm.1',  u'qlnv.1'])`

I would like to reshape the data frame like:

```
name    v    Qv    vm    qlnv
1       1    2     3     4
2       5    6     7     8
```

How could I do that ? Is there maybe a feature of the csv parser that can do the work ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this effect with help of numpy. df denotes your dataframe with results in one row. I assume that there are 4 features for each line.

```
import numpy as np
pd.DataFrame(np.array(df).reshape(df.shape[0]*df.shape[1]/4,4))
```

Comment: shure it should not be `df.shape[0] * df.shape[1]/4` ?

Comment: Of course you are right. I corrected my answer. I wrongly assumed you have only one row of data.